# EF Core - Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have been getting `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ExchangeHours_Times_StartTimeId' on table 'ExchangeHours' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.` error, when trying to update the database through EF Core to MSSQLServer. The problem is in class ExchangeHour, which references class Time.

Classes:

```
public class ExchangeHour
{
    ...
    public int StartTimeId { get; set; }
    public Time StartTime { get; set; }
    public int EndTimeId { get; set; }
    public Time EndTime { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Time
{
    public int TimeId { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
}
```

MigrationScript regarding ExhangeHours.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ExchangeHours",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ExchangeId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    DayOfWeek = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    StartTimeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    EndTimeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    HourTypeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ExchangeHours", x => new { x.ExchangeId, x.DayOfWeek });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ExchangeHours_Times_EndTimeId",
                        column: x => x.EndTimeId,
                        principalTable: "Times",
                        principalColumn: "TimeId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ExchangeHours_Exchanges_ExchangeId",
                        column: x => x.ExchangeId,
                        principalTable: "Exchanges",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ExchangeHours_ExchangeHourTypes_HourTypeId",
                        column: x => x.HourTypeId,
                        principalTable: "ExchangeHourTypes",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ExchangeHours_Times_StartTimeId",
                        column: x => x.StartTimeId,
                        principalTable: "Times",
                        principalColumn: "TimeId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

When ExchangeHour will be deleted, I want to delete both Time References, as I will not need them anymore, so the cascade on Delete is something I want. But if I remove one of the references to class Time, update-migrations is without error. I don't see any cycle or anything wrong with this, so I'm not exactly sure, why this I can't use this. I didn't find any restrictions, that one class can't reference another multiple time. Any ideas why this throws this error?

Comment: What relationship between `ExchangeHour` and `Time`? 1 `ExchangeHour` to 1 `Time`, or 1 `Time` can be related to multiple `ExchangeHour`

Comment: `ExchangeHour` can have 2 `Time`, 1 `Time` can be related to 1 `ExchangeHour`

Comment: Well, seems it is a knows problem of some SQL servers, you can read more about this following link https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5871. The cite from there `unfortunately some relational databases, notably SQL Server, do not support having multiple cascade relationships`. There you can find possible workaround of handling cascade in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking if something similar might be it, but did not found anyting, thanks for the link.

Comment: So, no, there are no cycles but there are multiple cascade paths. No way to avoid this error but removing one cascaded delete and handling the cascaded delete in code. It's a nuisance.